# wierd formula needed (Reverse Formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a calculator in excel created to determine the percent of positive scores vs the overall scores as follows:

```
B10 = positive points
B12 = Negative points
B13 = `SUM(B10:B12)`
B14 = `(B10-B13)/B13`
```

In the following instance this is what I get:

```
B10 = 319
B11 = 18
B12 = 8
B13 = 345
B14 = 91%
```

What I need:
I want to be able to (in a separate cell)-utilizing the information obtained on cells `B10:B14`- ask excel how many more "positive" points will I need (should no additional negative points be added) to get to a higher percentage.

I have a data validation list on cell `C10` that has a dropdown of percent's from 90% to 99%.

I would like to have a formula in `C11`that will see the selection I make on `C10` from the percent dropdown and calculate how many more points I would need to add to `B10` in order to reach that percent and return with the amount of points needed.

In this example that I showed above, If I would have chosen the "94%" option from the dropdown list in `C10` then Excel would have given me =180 on cell `C11`(because should there be no more negative points, it would take an additional 180 positive points for the percent to go up to 94%.

Hope this is not extremely confusing! But definitely would appreciate the help as I've been breaking my brains to find a formula that works!

Comment: `(B10-B13)/B13` does not give 91% it gives 7.5%

Comment: Can you clear up a couple of things in this post? Idk what B11 is, and your math doesn't look like it adds up,

Comment: @MBurnham (I apologize as I did not believe it was necessary to tag `B11` but in any case `B11` are "passive" points that don't affect the scale in any way therefore the percentage equation does not account for it when we do (B10-B13).

Comment: @ScottCraner  I just ran it and =(319-8)/345 = 90% so you guys were right I made a mistake here it was not 91% it was 90%. Sorry

Comment: You have it `(B10-B13)/B13` which is `(319-345)/345`

Comment: Do these positive points take away from the negative points. Do they add to the total points possible

Comment: Positive, Passive and Negative all contribute to the "Overall" points but for the percentage only the negative points affect the Positive (in this example subtracting the negative 8 points from the positive 319 = 311/345(overall) and this gives 90%

Comment: Then please edit the formula you are showing for B14. it is wrong it should be `(B10-B12)/B13` not `(B10-B13)/B13`

Comment: *"Hope this is not extremely confusing!"*... It's not about *hope* but about making the necessary *effort*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brute force method.  Use this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(ROUND(IFERROR((B10+ROW(INDIRECT("1:1000"))-B12)/(B13+ROW(INDIRECT("1:1000"))),-1E+99),2)>=C10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:1000"))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This formula literally iterates through adding 1 to 1000 to the values till it reaches the percentage desired.

If you feel 1000 is too low you can change all of them to a higher number.

[image]

Comment: I tried this one and it returns = 14

it should return 180 (Since (311+180)/(345+180) = 94%

Comment: @RaphaelCodak see edit, you may need to refresh the screen.

Comment: Wow a lot of great input from everyone! this is it!

Answer (score 1):

In C11 write:
`=Round((B12+(B11+B12)*C10)/(1-C10),0)-B10`

C10 should be percentage like 94% not 94
Round will remove decimals
If you need the difference you need to deduct B10 initial value

Comment: This formula brought back over =540 (the factual result should be 180). this formula is also omitting both the positive points and the overall points which are key to deciphering this

Comment: I updated the formula to deduct the initial value B10 the result will be the additional points

Comment: @RaphaelCodak the difference between his return of `222` with the new formula and your 180 is where the rounding is done.  `222` is the number to get to `94%` where as `180` or my `179` gets you to `.9351` which rounded is `94%`.  So you need to ask yourself how accurate you want to be.

Comment: and what formula exactly is using to calculate the percentage

Comment: Sorry, I think this method is better, and have voted as such, wish I could give you more than one vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an algebra problem.

```
r is your desired rate
n is negative points
p is positive points
You start with r = p/(p + n), right?
rp + rn = p
rn = p - rp
rn = p(1 - r)
p = rn/(1 - r)
```

Someone should check my math, but you should be able to multiple your desired rate by the number of negative points and divide by one minus your desired rate.

Comment: So based on what you said this should be my formula/equation in cell `C11`

`=SUM(C10*(B12/(1-C10)))`  my only thing is based on this we are omitting the original base of the equation which was the positive points and the overall points.

Did I miss something on your response?

Comment: My formula would get you the total positive score needed to hit that percent with the current negative score, so you just subtract the current positive score: `=C10*B12/(1-C10)-B10`

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to work -at first- here is what I got
the result came back as a negative number -193 (but when I verify the 193 added points would give 94%!) but then I tried with 95% and something weird happened (the result was less -when in fact it should require more points to go up in percentage-) maybe a slight modification to this would work?

Comment: What numbers were you using for B10, B12, and C10?  It's working fine for any numbers I'm testing with

Answer (score 0):

```
[PosPoints] / [PossibleScore] = [Percent] / 100
```

So what you want to know is

```
([PosPoints] + X) / [PossibleScore + X] = [NewPercent] / 100
```

And if you solve for X, you get:

```
X = ((100 * [PosPoints]) - ([NewPercent] * [PossibleScore])) / ([NewPercent] - 100)
```

So your new possible score is

```
[PossibleScore] + X
```

Comment: Correct but the [PossibleScore] is what I need excel to give me when I provide it with the [NewPercent] and [ActualScore]

Comment: So more like this?